# Cannot embed interop type 'Microsoft.Office.Core...'

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2013, office-interop, com-interop

This question has been answered multiple times on stack overflow yet all of the solutions have not helped me any further. (changing 'Embed Interop Types to false)

I don't know what I did wrong but all of the sudden I've gotten over 200 errors

see entire error-list [here](http://paste.ofcode.org/LdHHfYqeU9bFYGmPVNmJ8b)

I tried running it with the errors to get a [different message](https://gyazo.com/72d523f636e8dae7ca4842d16be27776) and it tells me the .exe is missing, so I tried rebuilding it but that brings me back to the start.
It's also giving me ['random' casting errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiZhD.jpg), where before the error-storm it worked smoothly..

Comment: What errors do you get exactly? The mentioned link is broken.

Comment: something like this but multiply by 500 times (got it off a different website seeing that I'm not using Interop in my project anymore) 

Error 86 Cannot embed interop type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.AppEvents_Event' found in both assembly 'c:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel\11.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll' and 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office12\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll'. Consider setting the 'Embed Interop Types' property to false. PET

Answer (score 0):

The typical answer to this problem is to follow the suggestion in the error list, **set property to false `Embed Interop Types = false`**.

Upon that not working, I fixed this problem by removing all references to `Office interop` and re-adding them. It did not work until I found *all* of the imports. They have different prefixes so be sure you have them all removed before you begin re-adding them.

To be clear, I had the *exact* same situation you describe, which is hundreds of errors, and some new random casting errors.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I was going through the same error and didn't find any solution.

I looked into my project references, and there was more than one reference for the assembly `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`, one as `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` and other as `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel1`.

I removed one of them (more exactly the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel1`) and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score -1):

Try installing / reinstalling Microsoft Office. Your application uses a dll that is produced by the Office installation package.